# MySQL database to .TXT using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a form in html5 and on submit it runs the php script which then connects to the MySQL database, insert it into a table and then write down all the lines that are in the table to a .txt file.

For some reason it gives the following warnings:

```
1 record added
Warning: fopen(C:/xampp2/htdocs/bap000/opdr002_config.txt): failed to open stream: No error in C:\xampp2\htdocs\bap000\opdr002_input.php on line 25

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\bap000\opdr002_input.php on line 28

Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp2\htdocs\bap000\opdr002_input.php on line 33
```

The form:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>bap les</title>
</head>
<body>

<form name="formOne" method="post" action="opdr002_input.php">
Color:
<select name="color">
<option value="blue">Blue</option>
<option value="red">Red</option>
</select>
<br />
X:
<input type="number" name="xCord" maxlength="3" />
<br />
Y:
<input type="number" name="yCord" maxlength="3" />
<br />
Z:
<input type="number" name="zCord" maxlength="3" />
<br />

<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

the PHP script:

```
<?php
// Make connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","map_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Insert values into the Database
$sql = "INSERT INTO `map_db`.`lines` (`color`, `xCords`, `yCords`, `zCords`) VALUES
('$_POST[color]','$_POST[xCord]','$_POST[yCord]','$_POST[zCord]')";

// Check for errors
if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

// Redirect user to page saying:
echo "1 record added";

// $result will contain everything inside the lines table
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lines");
$data = null;
$theFile = fopen("C:/xampp2/htdocs/bap000/opdr002_config.txt", "W");

// Loop through the lines using $row
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data = $row['color'] . "," . $row['xCords'] . "," . $row['yCords'] . "," . $row['zCords'] . '\n';
    $addData = fputs($theFile, trim($data));
}

fclose($theFile);

// Close the connection
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com). As written, someone could ruin your entire website in seconds.

Comment: What is mode `W` meant to be? The documentation of the `fopen()` function does not define any modes with capital letters.

Comment: What @PetrR. means is: learn about the security advantages of mysqli and the "prepared statement" feature it offers.

Comment: Take a look [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) and see if you can find the problem... Also, make sure XAMP is able to write to the map ( with read and write permisions)

Comment: `'$_POST[color]'` must be `'" . $_POST['color'] . "'`.  The difference between `$arr[test]` and `$arr['test']` is, one element has a constant as identifier, the other a string.

Comment: Sorry, cannot edit the comment anymore: Also suggesting to use `fputcsv` instead of `fputs`.

Comment: @arkascha Changed it to w instead of W, this fixed remaining warnings, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the permissions of "opdr002_config.txt" - most likely php doesn't have write permission.

Also check if

> mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM lines");

is running properly.
try with:

> mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `map_db`.`lines`");

You might check the first query too.

See [this function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) for cheching the query errors.

Comment: Thanks! This fixed it, it now writes it to the .txt file, however... the "\n" doesn't work.